# Session variable for particular page/url

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, session, session-variables

I am using ASP.NET..........

It is possible to create a session variable on page load just for a particular page/url?

The problem that I have is: The user comes to page 1 and the session variable becomes A, then he opens page 2 in a new tab and the session variable because B on both page 1 and page 2.

So when the user needs the session variable on page 1 it does not work because the variable have changed!

Answer (score 2):

You can have more than one session variable. Just name the one on page A `Session["variableA"]` and the one on page B `Session["variableB"]`.

Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Cant do this because its the same page, but different values based on the query string.....

Comment: @Etienne: Can't you then just have a conditional statement to check for the query string value? And/or use it as the name for the session variable?

Comment: Yeah I think I will need to do that rather, will use the value from the query string and then just add some more values to it.

Comment: That's probably your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do that. Session variables are meant for the user's whole session. If you want to store page-specific information you need to round trip it between the server and the client on every request, for example by using the page's ViewState.

Tabbed browsing is a widespread feature these days and you have to design your sites so that they work correctly even if the user keeps switching tabs when interacting with your site.